# Create a clickable arc in a zoomable sunburst made within D3?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm still pretty new to coding since finishing my bootcamp a few months ago but I got an assignment at my current job now where I am to create a data visualization example with D3. I'm pretty lost on how to do a lot of stuff in D3 since there doesn't seem to be a lot of resources for it. The issue at hand is to create a sunburst diagram where each arc is clickable and updates a div in the html that will display a title and text box of information. I currently have the html setup for the layout of the page as well as the diagram itself but still not sure how to make it interactive. The data is hard coded currently in the js file so all objects have their information that needs to be called upon when clicked to update the div. Does anyone have any idea how that would be done?

[image]

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center" style="padding: 2rem;">Growth Opportunities</h1>
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div style="margin-right: 8rem; margin-left: 2rem;">
            <svg></svg>
        </div>
        <div class="card" style="width: 50rem; margin-right: 5rem;">
            <h2 class="card-header text-center" style="padding: 1rem;">Title</h2>
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text" style="padding: 1rem">Test Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
// Variables
var width = 750;
var height = 750;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);

// Create primary <g> element
var g = d3.select('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

// Data strucure
var partition = d3.partition()
  .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);

// Find data root
var root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
  .sum(function (d) { return d.size});

// Size arcs
partition(root);
var arc = d3.arc()
  .startAngle(function (d) { return d.x0 })
  .endAngle(function (d) { return d.x1 })
  .innerRadius(function (d) { return d.y0 })
  .outerRadius(function (d) { return d.y1 });

// Put it all together
g.selectAll('path')
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter().append('path')
  .attr("display", function (d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style('stroke', '#fff')
  .style("fill", function (d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register a listener function on each *path* element to interact with them on mouse click. This is done with the `on()` function on a d3 selection:

```
g.selectAll('path')
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter().append('path')
  ...
  .on('click', function(event, d) {
    d3.select(".card-text").text(<Your text here>);
  });
```

The function is being passed the click event and the current datum. The *this* variable is also set to the DOM element that was clicked.